# Gnuplotting gzipped files

Tags: gzip, gnuplot

I would like to use a command like

`plot 'datafile.gz' u 1:2`

in gnuplot for a data file that is gzipped.  Of course gnuplot does see that the file is gzipped and unzip it for me.  Is there a way to have gnuplot handle a gzipped file directly without me having to unzip it to disk first?

Answer (score 5):

If you feed gnuplot its commands from the unix command line, you can also pipe data to it from another program, like `zcat` which reads in a gzipped file and prints it out, e.g.:

```
zcat datafile.gz | gnuplot -p -e 'plot "-" u 1:2'
```

EDIT:

Apparently, in place of a filename, you can give gnuplot's `plot` command a shell command to run and use the output of. Just put a `<` in front:

```
plot "< zcat datafile.gz" u 1:2
```

You should be able to use that multiple times to do what you want.

(Answer courtesy of 
philipp.janert on the 'Gnuplot in Action' forum http://www.manning-sandbox.com/message.jspa?messageID=77092)

Comment: What if I'm not using the command line?  I often automatically generate gnuplot commands in a command file that references data in several files

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
gzcat datafile.gz | plot '-' u 1:2
```

Comment: That's useful and I'll use it for one file, but what if I'm plotting multiple files?